# How to add image for buttons in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to add image for buttons in flutter like below the image. Here i have used ElevatedButton. So How to set background image for the ElevatedButton. I do not know how to add image for it. If anyone know please help to find the solution.

```
  child:SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Wrap(
          alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
          runSpacing:  20.0, // Or more
          spacing: 20, // Or more
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 520,
            ), 
            SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity, // <-- Your width
                height: 50, // <-- Your height

            ),
            SizedBox(
                height: 50, // <-- Your height
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    onSignIn(context);
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Color(0xff557de3),
                      shape: StadiumBorder()

                  ),
                  child: const Text(
                    "GMAIL",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 13,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
                height: 50, // <-- Your height

                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    //validateForm(); 
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Color(0xff557de3),
                      shape: StadiumBorder()

                  ),
                  child: const Text(
                    "Phone",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 13,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),
                  ),
                ),// Button
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: you have to create your customButton for that.

Comment: I have to agree with @john, that you need a custom button for that. Maybe create a class from the solution below

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
ElevatedButton.icon(
                onPressed: (){},
                icon: Icon(Icons.phone), 
                label: Text("hello"),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add image from asset:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Image.asset('your_asset_path')
)
```

Or you can add network image:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Image.network('your_image_url_path')
)
```

Or you can create your custom button:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {},
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage('your_asset_image_path'),
      ),
    ),
  )  
)
```

Comment: But background color coming for the SizedBox, So how to remove it

Comment: Remove ```SizedBox()```

Answer (score 1):

You can use gestures detector

```
     GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            debugPrint('The image button has been tapped');
          },
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 300,
            height: 100,
            child: Image.network(
              'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

or use icon button

```
          IconButton(
          splashRadius: 100,
          iconSize: 200,
          icon: Ink.image(
            image: const NetworkImage(
                'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            // do something when the button is pressed
            debugPrint('Hi there');
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `ElevatedButton`, have you tried `IconButton`, `GestureDetector`, `InkWell`, `InkResponse` and `Material`?

```dart
 IconButton(
        splashRadius: 100, // optional
        onPressed: {YOUR_LOGIC_COMPONENT}
        icon: Container(
           child : {YOUR_WIDGET},
       ),
      ),
```

or

```
GestureDetector(
  child: SizedBox(child: {YOUR_WIDGET}),
  onTap: {YOUR_LOGIC_COMPONENT},
);
```

or

```
InkWell(
  child: CircleAvatar(child: {YOUR_WIDGET}),
  onTap: {YOUR_LOGIC_COMPONENT},
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MaterialButton` and customize it according to your need.

```
 MaterialButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        textColor: Colors.white,
        splashColor: Colors.red,
        elevation: 8.0,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(''), //some asset image
                fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: SizedBox(),
          ),
        ),
        // ),
        onPressed: () {
          print('Tapped');
        },
      ),
```